# Increment file name with each run of the code-Python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have a relatively simple python code that reads serial data from an arduino and outputs it into a csv file.

I am able to successfully save the data, but need it so that when the code is ran again, it makes a new file. (Data1...Data2...etc).

I have written a code that should do that, but it instead just adds more data to the first file and never makes any additional files:

```
import serial
import time
from datetime import datetime 
import os

timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#The purpose of this code is to read the data from the arduino and then save 
each string
# into a csv file, which can be retrieved via the RPi's USB. 

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200) #on the pi
#ser=serial.Serial('COM6',115200)   #on the pc

for i in range(1,100000):
    while True:
       str(ser.readline())

       s = [0]
       s[0] = str(ser.readline())
       s[0] = str(ser.readline())
       s[0] = str(ser.readline())


       while os.path.exists("TDRData%s.csv" % i):
           i += 1

       f = open("TDRData%s.csv" % i, "a+")
       f.write(timestamp+s[0])
```

I'm not sure exactly why it isn't working. I feel like my method is probably a bit lazy and could be optimized, so if there are any suggestions it would be great to hear them.

I have another minor question too, it isn't a pressing issue at the moment. But, the timestamp that is being printed onto the csv file is static. I need it to be dynamic with each line of data. Any work around for this?

Comment: you need to `close()` your filehandle

Comment: @JoelBerkeley or even better, use the `with` keyword... `with open("TDRData%s.csv" % i, "a+") as f:`. But the file handle isn't the problem, since the operating system closes any open resources when the process exits

Comment: I have made some edits to the code. Good and bad things have happened. The good: It is now making multiple files! The bad: It is printing each individual line in a new file.

Comment: @AaronGarton agreed it's not THE problem, but we don't want 100000 filehandles open

Comment: Now, whenever I run the program, it starts at TDRData4.csv, rather than TDRData1.csv. This leads me to believe something is open that is causing this error.

Comment: open you file before the loop  or create it only if it hasn't already been opened. Stackexchange is not about debuging your code

Comment: @MichaelDoubez I'm not asking for it to be debugged. I'm actively debugging it myself. My post specifically asks for recommendations or suggestions to my method.

Comment: There are so many problems with the code that it would be better to ask someone to walk you through it: infinite loop, reading multiple time in the same variable ...

Comment: How will you ever get out of the `while True:` loop?